# foreach not returning expected results

Tags: php

I am having issues returning a valid response from the below code. The intention is to return a list of cities based upon post_title().

The print_r response indicates a response is being processed (see below) however when an echo on $city is undertaken it sends an error.

```
add_shortcode('citylist',function(){
global $wpdb;
$country = $wpdb->prefix . 'worldcities';
$title = wp_title("",false,'right');
$args = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT city_ascii FROM $country WHERE ranking < 2 AND country = '$title'");
foreach ($args as $city_ascii=>$city) {
        print_r ($city);;
};
} );
```

The print _r response is as follows (note Page_Title is "Nigeria".

```
StdClass Object ([city_ascii] => Ibadan) StdClass Object ([city_ascii] => Ogbomoso ...
```

All of the responses are expected and correct (ie. Ibadan, Ogbomoso etc).

However when this is replaced with echo, it throws an error. (see revised code below).

```
add_shortcode('citylist',function(){
global $wpdb;
$country = $wpdb->prefix . 'worldcities';
$title = wp_title("",false,'right');
$args = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT city_ascii FROM $country WHERE ranking < 2 AND country = '$title'");
foreach ($args as $city_ascii=>$city) {
        echo $city;;
};
} );
```

Any help would be appreciated.

(Note I have read the PHP manuals, reviewed previous posts here and on other boards already before anyone suggests this avenue).

Comment: Before going deeper: what do you see if you use `echo $city[0];` or `echo $city_ascii[0];`? Also, what do you see when you change the foreach to `foreach ($args as $city_ascii) {` ?

Comment: On both instances I get an "Uncaught Error Cannot Use object of type stdClass as array .." which is why I am slightly confused.

Comment: ***This code contains a major SQL injection attack***, you need to use `$wpdb->prepare` to sanitise and validate your variables instead of just including them directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `print_r()` statement shows that your `$wpdb` call is returning an array of **objects**, and you can't `echo` an object. (Unless the object has a [`__toString()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring) method, but `stdClass` doesn't.)

You need to get the property you seek from the object, like this: `$city->city_ascii`.

**Also**, [you shouldn't `echo` the content](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/#more-information) generated by a shortcode. You should instead `return` the string.

**Code edited** to use [`$wpdb->prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare) to protect against SQL injection (per @TomJNowell's comment).

```
add_shortcode('citylist',function(){
    global $wpdb;
    $content = '';
    $country = $wpdb->prefix . 'worldcities';
    $title = wp_title("",false,'right');
    $args = $wpdb->get_results( 
                $wpdb->prepare(
                   "SELECT city_ascii FROM %s WHERE ranking < 2 AND country = %s",
                   $country,
                   $title
            )
    );
    foreach ($args as $city_ascii=>$city) {
            $content .= esc_html( $city->city_ascii ) . '<br />';
    };
    return $content;
} );
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Pat_J. However I will need to put a <br> into this somewhere. Suggestions? (Note your suggestion was perfect!)

Comment: This answer contains a major SQL injection vulnerability, the query requires a `prepare` statement to avoid `$country` being used for attacks

Comment: You're right, @TomJNowell. That's what I get for copy-and-pasting from the OP.

Comment: Op probably didn't know, this is your chance to fix that!

Comment: Indeed. Done, and thanks for the catch!

Comment: @BretMadden - I've updated the code, both to protect you from SQL injection as @TomJNowell points out and to include a `<br />` tag in the string that will be returned. As long as it's a valid string, you can return anything from the shortcode callback.

Comment: Thanks @Pat J much appreciated!